# How do I get the jar file for Delta Lake 1.0.0 Library

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, delta-lake

I use Delta lake for doing upserts to my data in my Glue jobs. I usually put the jar file in S3 and use that location in Glue job.

I currently use Delta lake 0.6.1, for which I got the jar file from somewhere I don't remember now. The problem is it doesn't work for Spark 3.1.

So I tried to find the same for newest version for Delta Lake and couldn't find it. It would be great if someone could point me the right place.

Comment: "Tried to find" ... Where were you searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always find on the [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.delta/delta-core).  [Specific version, like, 1.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.delta/delta-core_2.12/1.0.0), always has a link to a jar file.